# Multiple lists of the same length to csv

Tags: list, csv

I have a couple `List<string>`s, with the format like this:

```
List 1  List 2  List 3

  1       A      One

  2       B      Two

  3       C      Three

  4       D      Four

  5       E      Five
```

So in code form, it's like:

`List<string> list1 = {"1","2","3","4","5"};`

`List<string> list2 = {"A","B","C","D","E"};`

`List<string> list3 = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};`

My questions are:

1. How do I transfom those three lists to a CSV format?

> ```
> list1,list2,list3
>
> 1,A,one
>
> 2,b,two
>
> 3,c,three
>
> 4,d,four
>
> 5,e,five
> ```

1. Should I append `,` to the end of each `index` or make the delimeter its own index within the multidimensional list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is your main concern, I would use an existing csv library for your language, as it's probably been pretty well optimized.

If that's too much overhead, and you just want a simple function, I use the same concept in some of my code. I use the `join/implode` function of a language to create a list of comma separated strings, then `join` that list with `\n`.

I'm used to doing this in a dynamic language, but you can see the concept in the following pseudocode example:

```
header = {"List1", "List2", "List3"}
list1 = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
list2 = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
list3 = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};

values = {header, list1, list2, list3};
for index in values
    values[index] = values[index].join(",");
values = values.join("\n");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity does this solution make the delimiter a separate item within the multidimensional list (I'm not familiar with your language, but it looks like you're using an array)?

Comment: No language. Just pseudocode. No, it doesn't change the array at all. The delimiter is added during the `join()`.